# Range Sum of BST using DFS

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, depth-first-search

**Problem:** Given the root node of a binary search tree, return the sum of values of all nodes with value between L and R (inclusive).

The binary search tree is guaranteed to have unique values.

Example 1:

Input: root = [10,5,15,3,7,null,18], L = 7, R = 15

Output: 32

Leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/

**My approach:** I'm trying to do a dfs and visit each node, if the value at that node fits the constraints then I want to return it in my recursive function. I then add up all the values and return that to my main function.

I'm still trying to understand recursion, what am I doing wrong in this code (why does it only return 10 and not 32?).

I'm trying to return a value from each recursive function and add it in the end - does that make sense to do?

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int L, int R) {
        if(root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        rangeBST(root, L, R);
        
        return rangeBST(root, L, R);
    }
    
    public static int rangeBST(TreeNode root, int L, int R) {
        if(root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        if(root.val >= L && root.val <= R) {
            return root.val;
        }

        int x = rangeBST(root.left, L, R);
        int y = rangeBST(root.right, L, R);
        
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- The algorithm should recur deeper when the value is between the L-R range, but instead your returns the current node's own value without looking any deeper.
- The algorithm should not always need to visit *each* node, but take advantage of the BST property: it should only search in the left subtree when the current value would not exclude to find any in-range values in that subtree.

  For instance, if the current node has value 3, and the L-R range is (5,9), then it makes no sense to look further in the left subtree, as there *all* values are guaranteed to be less than 3, no matter how big that subtree may be.

  A similar observation may hold for the right subtree.

```
class Solution {
    public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int L, int R) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        int val = 0;
        if (root.val >= L && root.val <= R) val += root.val;
        if (root.val < R) val += rangeSumBST(root.right, L, R);
        if (root.val > L) val += rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R);
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I absolutely agree with your first issue, but I don´t think the second one is really an issue, because you still have a runtime complexity of O (N) (it did not change) but you have to add further Cyclomatic complexity, to improve the intermediate runtime for random cases of binary trees. This should only be done, if it is proven that this function is a bottleneck.

Comment: I don't claim that the time complexity changed, but I consider it still an issue, as the time complexity for the best case improves from *O(n)* to *O(1)*, and this can have considerable effect on the run time on sites where that is measured and results in a comparative score (like here: Leetcode). It is even possible to write a *O(n)* solution that runs into a TLE. So not only the time complexity is important, also the absolute running time.

Comment: Yes, it can have a significant effect on the absolute running time. But if it is not absolutely necessary to optimize runtime, I would not add further logic, because you have more possible mutators, error sources and maintainability issues.

Comment: That is your free choice. I prefer to make use of the given information that this concerns a BST and not just a binary tree. The additional `if` conditions are typical for BSTs, and so it is *expected* to have such logic in all the code that deals with navigation in a BST.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to add these values at the end and work with return values is correct. (In languages with pointer arithmetic or by reference variable passing, you could pass a reference to a integer and increase the recerenced value, without a return value.)
But in te line with the "return root.val" you have a problem.

```
public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int l, int r) {
        if(root == null)
            return 0;

        // This is a problem because you are stopping with your recursive search
        // if one value was found. This is the reason because it is returning 10 in your example
        // if(root.val >= L && root.val <= R) return root.val;

        int result = 0;
        // So your looking at your node, if the value is in the range you want.
        if (root.val >= l && root.val <= r)
            result += root.val;

        // Add the ranged summ of your left node
        result += rangeSumBST(root.left, l, r);
        // Add the ranged summ of your right node
        result += rangeSumBST(root.right, l, r);

        // And your done
        return result;
    }
```